# Laravel 5.2 getDirty always empty array

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to log all changes at my database (mysql db).

I need to know which fields where updated and from which tables, so after some research I came across the `getDirty()` method, but it is always returning an empty array, here is my simple code example:

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
    {
        $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
        $article->update($request->all());
        return $article->getDirty();
    }
```

Any idea why nothing is being returned?

Comment: Do you have the attributes whitelisted for Mass assignment?

Comment: @MinaAbadir yes `protected $fillable = [
     'title',
     'body',
     'published_at',
    ];`

Comment: And the values for title or body or published_at changed? Because, same value will not mark them as dirty, even if they are submitted in the form.

Comment: @MinaAbadir yes the title was changed, but nothing in the dirty array

Answer (score 8, accepted):

it's because you call `$article->getDirty();` after updating the database.

You can use the model events for this, there are many events like `saving`, `updating`, `deleting` ... for more details [look here](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent#events)

```
class SomeModel extends Eloquent {

  protected static function boot()
  {
    parent::boot();  // don't forget to call the parent boot method
    //On saving
    static::saving(
      function($record)
      {
        $dirty = $record->getDirty();
        foreach ($dirty as $field => $newdata)
        {
          $olddata = $record->getOriginal($field);
          if ($olddata != $newdata)
          {
            // Do what it takes here :)
          }
        }
        return true;
      }
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can I ask, how can I post some other parameter to saving method? (ie. user id and other info, so I can record who is what changing)

Comment: @Autista_z You can get the user who did this modification by calling `Auth::user()` and then you can query the other needed infos.

Comment: Thanks, I know, that I can use Auth::user, but what in case of cron job? When user is not logged in, but data are updating on users planned action.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do something like that

```
public function update($id, Request $request)
{
    $article = Article::findOrFail($id);
    $article->fill($request->all());
    //... your logic $article->getDirty() or $article->isDirty('column_name') 
    $article->save();
    return $article;
}
```